# How to allocate job to all CPUs on a cluster using slurm?

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I am running a python script that uses multiprocessing (uses all 64 cores) and when I try to run one of these jobs on a cluster node, it is running 64 processes on only 32 of the available cores (so all of them are running at 50%). When I try to change --cpus-per-task to 64 it says that the CPU configuration is unavailable. I have tried --threads-per-core == 2 and that did not work as well.

If anyone knows how to access all of the CPUs of a node using slurm, please help!

This is the info from scontrol show nodes:

```
[first line missing]
CPUAlloc=32 CPUTot=32 CPULoad=64.06 
AvailableFeatures=cloud
ActiveFeatures=cloud
Gres=(null)
NodeAddr=ai-cluster-hpc-pg0-1 NodeHostName=ai-cluster-hpc-pg0-1 Version=20.11.7 OS=Linux 5.4.0-1064-azure #67~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 11:38:21 UTC 2021 
RealMemory=124518 AllocMem=124512 FreeMem=122462 Sockets=16 Boards=1
State=ALLOCATED+CLOUD ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
Partitions=hpc BootTime=2022-01-16T03:32:58 SlurmdStartTime=2022-01-16T03:38:29
CfgTRES=cpu=32,mem=124518M,billing=32
AllocTRES=cpu=32,mem=124512M
CapWatts=n/a
CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
Comment=(null)
```

Jobscript:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# 
#SBATCH --job-name=preprocess 
#SBATCH --output=preprocess/slurm.out 
#SBATCH --nodes=1 
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1 
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32 
#SBATCH --array=0-30
```

Comment: It would be good to have a bit more information. Could you add your jobscript and the command you use to start the job? Additionally, could you add the output of `scontrol show node <nodename>` of one of the nodes you're trying to run your code on?

Comment: This is the info from scontrol show nodes: PUAlloc=32 CPUTot=32 CPULoad=64.06
   AvailableFeatures=cloud
   ActiveFeatures=cloud
   Gres=(null)
   NodeAddr=ai-cluster-hpc-pg0-1 NodeHostName=ai-cluster-hpc-pg0-1 Version=20.11.7
   OS=Linux 5.4.0-1064-azure #67~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 11:38:21 UTC 2021 
   RealMemory=124518 AllocMem=124512 FreeMem=122462 Sockets=16 Boards=1
   State=ALLOCATED+CLOUD ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=hpc 
   BootTime=2022-01-16T03:32:58 SlurmdStartTime=2022-01-16T03:38:29

Comment: CfgTRES=cpu=32,mem=124518M,billing=32
   AllocTRES=cpu=32,mem=124512M
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
   Comment=(null)

Comment: I am using the sbatch command and this is my script #!/bin/bash # #SBATCH --job-name=preprocess #SBATCH --output=preprocess/slurm.out #SBATCH --nodes=1 #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1 #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32 #SBATCH --array=0-30

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the output of `scontrol show nodes`, your nodes are configured with 32 CPUs each. It seems that the nodes only have 32 CPUs available and CPUs are the smalled unit that Slurm knows, i.e. if hyperthreading is used (threadspercore=2), each *CPU* in Slurm is one *Thread*.

As I see it, your node has 16 cores with two threads each. So trying to run 64 threads on them, will result in each thread only getting 50%.